# Express session is not working with "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

Iam trying to provide authentication for my node js application.For that Iam using express-session npm.Basically what I was trying is when I when my credentials are correct in my /login page.It should start the session and take me to /admin page.So that /admin will be directly accessible for some time in other tabs.And when I click on logout button,it should take me to main page and session should be cancelled and /admin page shouldnt be accessible directly and redirect to /login page.

I tried starting the session when login is success,but its giving me the Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

app.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'securedsession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)
    }
}));
var auth = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.user === "admin" && req.session.admin)
        return next();
    else
        return res.sendStatus(401);
};
app.post('/verifylogin', function(req, res) {
            var username = req.headers.uname;
            var password = req.headers.pwd;
            if (!username || !password) {
                res.send('login failed');
            } else if (username === "admin" || password === "adminnn") {
                req.session.user = "admin";
                req.session.admin = true;
                res.contentType('application/json');
                var data = JSON.stringify('/admin');
                res.header('Content-Length', data.length);
                res.send(data);
            }
            app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
                req.session.destroy();
                res.send("logout success!");
});

app.get('/admin', auth, function(req, res, next) {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/admin.html');
 });
```

login.html

```
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login() {
    var uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/verifylogin',
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "uname": uname,
            "pwd": pwd
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location = data;
        }
    });
}
</script>
<h1>Login</h1>
<p>
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname" />
</p>
<p>
    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" /><br/>
</p>
<p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</p>
```

Can someone help me out the mistake I was doing if any here and how to fix this and start the session

*********edited

Latest code after the suggestions,even the creds are correct,it is redirecting me to unauthorized rather than,/admin .can u have a look

app.js

```
    var app = express();
var d = new Date();
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'securedsession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        maxAge: d.getTime() + 10
    }
}));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.post('/verifylogin', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.uname;
    var password = req.body.pwd;
    var uname = "admin";
    var pwd = "admin@123";
    if (uname == username && pwd == password) {
        console.log("success");
        req.session.user = "admin";
        req.session.admin = true;
        req.session.save();
        console.log("resdasdasda", req.session);
        res.contentType('application/json');
        var data = JSON.stringify('/admin');
        res.header('Content-Length', data.length);
        res.send(data);
    } else {
        console.log("fail");
        res.send("Bad luck");
    }
});
var auth = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.user === "admin" && req.session.admin)
        return next();
    else
        return res.sendStatus(401);
};
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/views/home.html'));
});
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/login.html');
});
app.get('/admin', auth, function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/admin.html');
});
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.send("logout success!");
});
module.exports = app;
```

html

```
 <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function login() {
    var uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
    $.ajax({
      url : '/verifylogin',
      type : "POST",
      data : {
        "uname":uname,
        "pwd" :pwd
      },
        success: function(data) {
        window.location = data;
        }
      });
}
</script>
<h1>Login</h1>
<p>
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname" />
</p>
<p>
     <label class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" /><br/>
</p>
<p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you please properly indent the code in your question.  It's really not readable the way it is.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ive indented properly.can u have a look,why it is not taking me to /admin

Answer (score 1):

The error you report is caused when you have more than one `res.send()` for the same request.  So, you're looking for something in your code that can cause that.

When you properly indent part of your code, it looks like this:

```
app.post('/verifylogin', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.headers.uname;
    var password = req.headers.pwd;
    if (!username || !password) {
        res.send('login failed');
    } else if (username === "admin" || password === "adminnn") {
        req.session.user = "admin";
        req.session.admin = true;
        res.contentType('application/json');
        var data = JSON.stringify('/admin');
        res.header('Content-Length', data.length);
        res.send(data);
    }

    app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.session.destroy();
        res.send("logout success!");
    });
});
```

Which means you have an `app.get()` inside an `app.post()` which is never the right way to do things.  This will lead to multiple `app.get('/logout')` handlers getting installed and thus you will try to do `res.send()` multiple times for a the /logout request.

This should be like this:

```
app.post('/verifylogin', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.headers.uname;
    var password = req.headers.pwd;
    if (!username || !password) {
        res.send('login failed');
    } else if (username === "admin" || password === "adminnn") {
        req.session.user = "admin";
        req.session.admin = true;
        res.contentType('application/json');
        var data = JSON.stringify('/admin');
        res.header('Content-Length', data.length);
        res.send(data);
    }
});

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.send("logout success!");
});
```

---

Based on your edits, I would suggest you avoid any kind of race condition with saving the session by changing to this:

```
app.post('/verifylogin', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.uname;
    var password = req.body.pwd;
    var uname = "admin";
    var pwd = "admin@123";
    if (uname === username && pwd === password) {
        console.log("success");
        req.session.user = "admin";
        req.session.admin = true;
        req.session.save(() => {
            console.log("resdasdasda", req.session);
            res.json(data);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("fail");
        res.send("Bad luck");
    }
});
```

Other than that, the only other thing I can think of that would cause you to lose your session would be the browser losing the session cookie.  You can check that on the browser side by examining the network tab in the Chrome debugger and seeing if the desired session cookie is being sent with the request for `/admin`.

Comment: Yes .Thanks.I found the issue that Iam using res.send() twice removed the first..But even though my creds are correct.it is giving unauthorized..why do u think this behaviour.It is not taking me to /admin

Comment: I ve edited my quest and added my /admin at the end..can u have a look and plz tell me if any thing is wrong as it is giving me unauthorized

Comment: @user7350714 - We'd have to see more of your code to have an idea why your session isn't working.  Some session managers require you to call `req.session.save()` even though you have `resave: true` for the session changes to stick.

Comment: @user7350714 - If you want to require a valid session login before any of your routes, then you would put a test for the session in middleware that run before any route that requires login (so most routes except the /login route) and it checks for a valid session and if it's not there, then the middleware returns an error page and does not pass control on to your other route handlers.  That's typically how you check for session login validation before allowing other route handlers to run.

Comment: If u observe from /verifylogin Im doing res.send() to client side there I observe those session is getting lost and so at 'auth' in /admin Im getting those values as null.Any comments here?

Comment: @user7350714 - Did you read and understand my prior comment?  Login validation should be in middleware that is called before any route that requires login.  And, you probably have to save your session changes with `req.session.save()` after you change anything in the session for the change to stick.

Comment: ..yes I moved /verifylogin and before any route and added  req.session.save() but still the same issue,taking me to unauthorized...I tried to console the req.session.user at /admin and it gave me undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138760/discussion-between-user7350714-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @user7350714 - I'd suggest you add the latest version of code you tried that incorporates the suggestions to the end of your question so we can see exactly what you have last tried.  The code you've included in your question does not check authentication for routes other than the /admin route.  FYI, it's odd to put username/password in custom headers on a POST.  Usually, they would be the post data in the body.

Comment: @jfriend00..I've added the latest code under the edit